# Ajuda com conexão ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Ola! Sou novo no php e estou iniciando com ajax, gostaria de uma ajuda pois estou travado nesse projeto.
Estou passando essa conexão ajax e usando o return dados para enviar o objeto para minha outra função.
Porem o meu console log mostra que estou enviando uma string e não um objeto como era o esperado.

```js
function carregarDados(arquivo, type, dados, metodo){

    $.ajax({
        url: '../controller/'+arquivo+'Controller.php?metodo='+metodo,
        type: type,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: dados,
        success: function(dados){

        }
    });

    return dados;

}

function logar(){

    var dados = $('#formLogin').serialize();
    var retorno = carregarDados('login', 'post', dados, 'logar');

    console.log(retorno);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Envia string pois o método `serialize` do jQuery retorna uma string. Use o método `serializeArray` para obter um array com os nomes e valores dos campos.
Por exemplo o formulário HTML:

```html
 <form onsubmit="logar()" id="formLogin">
    <input type="text" name="login" value="admin">
    <input type="text" name="senha"value="123">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
```

Com `serializeArray`:

```js
[{
  name: "login",
  value: "admin"
}, {
  name: "senha",
  value: "123"
}]
```